# Identify SMD tactile switch

Tags: switches, identification, surface-mount

Do SMD markings not apply to switches?

Here is a Matsushita switch on a keypad matrix from circa 2008:

[image: Matsushita 89R: Tactile Switch]

The top is stamped with "8", "9", "R", and ":". It has the following measurements:

- 6.31mm width (body 6.31mm square)
- 6.90mm length with J-legs
- 3.6mm total height

[image: Matsushita tactile switch]

Pulling this one was a major pain - pads lifted way too easily. Luckily one of those pads is mechanical only. They will need some TLC (and probably some bonding agent.)

The closest I can find is a Panasonic [EVP-BFAC1A000](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic/EVP-BFAC1A000?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsgGjVA3toVBOmfPZklBYyzP9LUwgzSBsM%3D) but this is not an exact match.  Can anyone positively ID this switch?

Comment: does it matter that much? You could just find one with similar dimensions

Comment: I like Grayhill

Comment: Looks like you melted D65 too.

Comment: @BeB00 I have no way to accurately measure actuating force, so that alone means that any other replacement could "feel" different. A little difference is ok, but a large difference would make this key stand out from the others. Ron, D65 tests ok but has a rounded corner, possibly my fault.

Comment: If you can go at a store and try them, you could find one with the same feel... Next time use a hot air gun to unsolder SMD parts. :) If you need to do this many times it's worth buying one. + You can solder thermoplastics with it.

Comment: I have hot air, but that wouldn't have helped.  This particular PCB just didn't bond the copper well, or the bond deteriorated.  And RoHS solder - high temp and weak bonding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's from the Panasonic EVQQW series, see the [datasheet](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Switches%20PDFs/EVQ_PH_QW.pdf) page 3.

However, I can't find out what the numbers mean